Programmatically Intent based WhatsApp Image Sharing: Challenges with Biometric Authentication
In an android app, I am using intent to share an image via whatapp ( with Biometic lock enabled)
Whatspp is not able to hold that image ( nor send that image). it just open the specifc chat but with no attachment to send.
It was working before ( 1-2 Weeks back ). I know something is changed from Whataspp side.
private void openWhatsAppAndTelegram(String packageName, SecureRentTaking_GetterSetter activity, String caption) {
            File appFolderLocation = new File(cachePath, OUTPUT_RENT_RECEIPT_PNG_NAME);
            Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity.mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.concat(".provider"), appFolderLocation);

            if (contentUri == null) {
                In_Place.toastHelper.toastErrorMsg("File Not Present");
            } else {
                String toNumber = getFormattedNumber(activity.getTenantContactNumber());//getFormattedWatsAppNumber(activity.getTenantContactNumber());
                toNumber = toNumber.replace("+", "").replace(" ", ""); // E164 format without '+' sign

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, caption);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
                sendIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, activity.mContext.getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
                sendIntent.putExtra("jid", toNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix
                sendIntent.setPackage(packageName); //com.whatsapp //com.whatsapp.w4b
                sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(activity.mContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    activity.mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Choose an app"));
                } else {
                    In_Place.toastHelper.toastErrorMsg("App is not Installed");
                    // WhatsApp is not installed, handle accordingly
                    // You can prompt the user to install WhatsApp or use a different method to send messages
                }


            }

        }

I have found one issue which is similar ( but without any fix/workaround)
Ref : Sharing Content to WhatsApp Fails When AppLock is Enabled

Please note that, this works fine if Whatsapp has its Biometric lock disabled

Unfortunately, there's no universally reliable way to directly check if AppLock is enabled for a specific app like WhatsApp within the standard Android development tools

I noticed the same too. Super annoying.

Aditya Pruthi, please don't add Me too as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then ask it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you are interested in this specific question, you can upvote it, leave a comment, or start a bounty once you have enough reputation.
